# Maximizing product given a constraint on sum

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I wish to maximize or upper bound the product $(x_1+1).(x_2+1)\cdots(x_n+1)$ where $\forall i$ $x_i$ is non-negative integer i.e. $x_i \geq 0$. It is given that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = b$, where $1 \leq n \leq b$. Note that n is not fixed, but b is fixed. I can vary n to maximize this product.

Using the AM-GM inequality, the product would be maximum when all $x_i$ are equal to say $x$. So then restriction on sum would give $x = \frac{b}{n}$. This means $n \vert b$. I believe that this product will be maximum when $n = b, x = 1$ and hence product $= 2^b$. But, I am not able to prove this formally. Can anyone give their valuable inputs?

Comment: You may use the *mixing variables* approach. Prove that, if $x_1,x_2$ are replaced by $\tilde{x_1},\tilde{x_2}$ with the same sum but a smaller difference in absolute value, $$\left(\tilde{x_1}+1\right)\left(\tilde{x_2}+1\right)\geq \left(x_1+1\right)\left(x_2+1\right)$$ hence the greatest product is achieved when all the $x_i$s are "as equal as possible".

Comment: @Jack: But the real problem is to see how the resulting products vary with $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: and the previous comment shows that the product is maximized when $x_i\in\left\{\left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor , \left\lceil \frac{b}{n}\right\rceil \right\}$.

Comment: @Jack: But $n$ isn’t fixed: for each $n\le b$ we get a maximum product, and we want to choose the $n$ for which that maximum product is maximal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: all right, but the previous comments just solve the dual problem and show that *the maximal maximum* is achieved at $n=b$, don't they?

Comment: @Jack: Do they? I may be missing something obvious, but I don’t immediately see how. Oh, wait: we can pad the shorter products with $1$s.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: consider the maximum product for some $n$ (now that you know how we must take the $x_i$ to get it) and for $n+1$. Since we know how to arrange the $x_i$s to get the new maximum product, it is trivial that the new product is greater.

Comment: @Jack: There was never any question about how to get the $x_k$. And no, I don’t see that it’s trivial that the new product is greater, though as I said, I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Karamata! - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct. The trick is to realize that we can always consider $x_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,b$: we just set $x_k=0$ for $k=n+1,\ldots,b$, since this affects neither the sum of the $x_k$ nor the product of the $x_k+1$. We may also assume that $x_1\ge x_2\ge\ldots\ge x_b$. If there are $k$ and $\ell$ such that $x_k-x_\ell\ge 2$, we observe that

$$\begin{align*}
\big((x_k-1)+1\big)\big((x_\ell+1)+1\big)&=x_k(x_\ell+2)\\
&=x_kx_\ell+2x_k\\
&>x_kx_\ell+x_k+x_\ell+1\\
&=(x_k+1)(x_\ell+1)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so we can increase the product by decreasing $x_k$ by $1$ and increasing $x_\ell$ by $1$. If $x_1>1$, then necessarily $x_b=0$, so the maximum can be increased. Thus, at the maximum we must have $x_k=1$ for $k=1,\ldots,b$, making $n=b$ and the product $2^b$.

Comment: I understand it now. Please check my understanding: Suppose $(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\cdots(x_n+1) > 2^b$ for some $n$ strictly less than b, then this will contradict the AM-GM inequality fact that $(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\cdots(x_b+1)$ is maximum for $x_1 = \cdots = x_b = 1$. And this was possible due to your padding argument because adding 0 does not affect sum, and their increments by 1 also don't affect the product. i.e our claim that $(x_1+1)\cdots(x_n+1)(0+1)(0+1)\cdots(0+1)$ is not maximum because all $x_1 \cdots x_b$ are not equal

Comment: @Pranav: You can look at it that way. I prefer not to use the AM-GM inequality here, since the $x_k$ are required to be integers; I prefer the calculation that I gave showing that if two of them are more than $1$ unit apart, you can increase the product by decrementing the larger and incrementing the smaller. Thus, as Jack said in the comments, the maximum is when all $x_k\in\{\lfloor b/n\rfloor,\lceil b/n\rceil\}$, where $n$ is the number of non-zero $x_k$. After that the fact that $\sum_kx_k=b$ forces the conclusion that all $x_k=1$.

Comment: But wrt to Jack arguments if I choose $n = b/2$, then $x_1,x_2$ both lie in the given range and their sum is also b

Comment: @Pranav: That would be setting $n=2$, not $n=b/2$ (even assuming that $b$ is even). Yes, in that case $x_1$ and $x_2$ would be $b/2$ if $b$ is even, and if $b=2m+1$, then one of them would be $m$ and the other would be $m+1$. But I don’t see the relevance: the argument that I gave shows that the product can always be increased if $n<b$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I understand your logic now. We keep on decrementing any bigger value and incrementing a 0 corresponding to that, till all become 1

Comment: @Pranav: Now you’ve got it. Yes, that’s exactly right.